# NgIF analog in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

In my application every user has some permissions. 
For example view consist of 5 parts and 'normalUser' can work with 2 parts and 'superUser' with all 5.
How can hide this 3 part for 'normalUser'?

Is 'ngIf' good solution for this? Or someone knows better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a viable solution. If your parts are grouped together by user role, you could wrap the 'normalUser' parts in a component and your 'superUser' part in another component. Then use *ngIf to show\hide them based on the permission of the logged in user. Otherwise, you could also use [*ngSwitch](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) to shuffle between multiple templates.

Please provide a code sample if you want a more concrete answer.